# What does each SVN automatic conflict resolution action perform?

Tags: svn

I wrote a batch script which recursively updates my source code against the company's working base. When conflicts occur, it prompts for an action. What is the difference between 'base' and 'theirs-full'? Does 'mine-full' means "keep my changes at the working copy, I'll commit them later"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.resolve

In summary:

base

Choose the file that was the BASE revision before you updated your working copy. That is, the file that you checked out before you made your latest edits.

working

Assuming that you've manually handled the conflict resolution, choose the version of the file as it currently stands in your working copy.

mine-full

Resolve all conflicted files with copies of the files as they stood immediately before you ran svn update.

theirs-full

Resolve all conflicted files with copies of the files that were fetched from the server when you ran svn update.